# Passing $_POST variables to new URL then back to previous URL - best practice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form on index.php that does AJAX validation with an onblur event and PHP validation in the case that javascript is disabled.  Both the AJAX call and the PHP form action direct the user to validate.php which checks the validation_type and processes according to whether it's "ajax" or "php".  If AJAX validation is successful and no error messages are shown, then the user is allowed to submit the form and it redirects to validate.php with the $_POST variables. I need validate.php to pass back all the $_POST variables that were submitted with the form back to index.php (or any other URL throughout the project depending on where a form exists) along with a result equal to "success".  What's a way to solve this that's reusable across all forms in my project in the most secure way?

```
<form action="validate.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="validation_type" value="php"/>

<input type="text" name="user_first_name" id="user_first_name" value="" onblur="validate(this.value, this.id)" />

</form>
```

Comment: Do you foresee this being the case *ever* `in the case that javascript is disabled` and  even if so, will your entire web app have fallbacks for this unusual scenario?

Comment: Something like 2% of users have JavaScript disabled. I'm not sure if it's really necessary for you to try to cater to this demographic when you could just have a banner which says JavaScript is required. That said, the only way I could see you doing this without the user interacting with another form is storing all of the $_POST values in a PHP session (which you could also do in your ajax), then just use the session variables instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: I recommend you a different approach: make your validations as a function, and include that function in every place where you need validation. If validation passes, you get a TRUE, otherwise an array full of errors. In this way, you don't need to push POST variables back and forth between the server and the client and the whole problem is gone ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should use sessions. Save the $_POST values from the form in validate.php into [session variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). You can now access them on every page as long as the session continues.

Comment: Thanks @PaulS, this solved it!